# Mimic MUI TextField Label Behavior

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am building a custom input field which has a MUI Grid as it's base. I'm trying to create the label effect that MUI has for the 'outlined' variant (such that it does not show the border where the label is).

My initial solution was setting a background color to the label but that doesn't work since the background color of the input and the background color of the page can be different. MUI's TextField component seems to cover this (See image).
[image]

Any idea how to implement this using MUI V4?